# Python logging not writing in log

Tags: python-3.x, logging

The code looks like this:

```
def analysis():
    logging.basicConfig( filename='exception1.log', filemode='a', level=logging.ERROR, format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logging.FileHandler('/home/aim/top/exception1.log')

    try:
        some_func()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
         cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FAILED'")
         mydb.commit()
    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FINISHED'")
        mydb.commit() 
        cur.close()

def analysis1():
    logging.basicConfig( filename='exception2.log', filemode='a', level=logging.ERROR, format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logging.FileHandler('/home/aim/top-dev/exception1.log')

    try:
        some_func()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
         cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FAILED'")
         mydb.commit()
    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FINISHED'")
        mydb.commit() 
        cur.close()


def process():
    if req_type==1:
       analysis()
    if req_type==2:
       analysis1()
```

After running and getting exception the mysql commands are properly implemented, the log files in the two different directories are created but no errors are written in any of the two files. They are blank. What am I doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.ERROR):
"""To setup as many loggers as you want"""
    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, 'a')        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

This function creates two separate logging for the functions with different names when it is called inside each function.

```
def analysis():
logging.basicConfig( filename='logfile.log', filemode='a', level=logging.ERROR, format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.FileHandler('/logfile.log')

    try:
        some_func()
    except Exception as e:
        first_logger = setup_logger('first_logger', '/logfile.log')
        first_logger.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FAILED'")
        mydb.commit()
    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FINISHED'")
        mydb.commit() 
        cur.close()

def analysis1():
    logging.basicConfig( filename='logfile2.log', filemode='a', level=logging.ERROR, format= '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logging.FileHandler('/logfile2.log')

    try:
        some_func()
    except Exception as e:
        seccond_logger = setup_logger('second_logger', '/logfile2.log')
        second_logger.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FAILED'")
        mydb.commit()
    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE column SET STATUS='FINISHED'")
        mydb.commit() 
        cur.close()


def process():
    if req_type==1:
    analysis()
    if req_type==2:
    analysis1()
```

Since only one instance of the logging was created for both the functions it did not work.